# Postpositive "concerned": temporary state of affairs

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles, postpositive

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* reads

> Postpositive *present* (or *absent*) denotes a **temporary state of
>   affairs**: compare *the present government*. The same applies to
>   *involved* and *concerned*, though here the attributive sense differs more (cf. *deeply involved activists, concerned parents*).

However, *oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com* does not seem to include the second meaning as an adjective

> CONCERN: [often passive] to affect/involve
>   somebody/something: *Don't interfere in
>   what doesn't concern you. The loss was a tragedy for all concerned (=
>   all those affected by it).*

What does **temporary state of affairs** mean in this context? How does it distinguish the postpositive concerned?

Comment: 'The present sheriff' means the one in office for the time being. They are temporarily in office.  'The sheriff present' means the one in attendance at the meeting, say.

Comment: *Oxford Learner's Dictionary* is a learner's dictionary—it doesn't list all the meanings of every word, just the most common ones. Look at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned) definition 2b.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I understand your point.  However, surely the point of 'present' in this 'postpositive' use is not that the person is (or was) in office temporarily: all office holders are in office 'temporarily'  (except the Queen, members of the US Supreme Court and others appointed for life).  Isn't the point that the holder of the post is sheriff at the time referred to in the sentence?

Comment: @Tuffy: *postpositive* means *after the noun*. *The present sheriff* is the one currently in office. *The sheriff present* is the one who is in the room with you at this very moment. The second usage is considerably more temporary than the first.

Comment: @Tuffy I'm just showing that the CGEL comment is applicable, not that it's necessarily all that useful as a classification or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your reading of CGEL's text needs to be revisited. Let's add back some **context**:

> **[12] ii *the people present*, *the cars involved*, *the students concerned*, *the city proper* . . .**
>
> **The adjectives in [12ii] occur both attributively and postpositively, but with a difference in sense.** Postpositive
>   *present* (or *absent*) denotes a temporary state of affairs: compare *the present government*. The same applies to *involved* and *concerned*, though here the attributive sense differs more (cf. *deeply involved activists*, *concerned parents*).

Now let's delete the intervening sentence about a temporary state of affairs (which pertains only to *present* and *absent*):

> The adjectives in [12ii] occur both attributively and postpositively,
>   but with a difference in sense. . . . The same applies to *involved*
>   and *concerned*, though here the attributive sense differs more (cf.
>   *deeply involved activists*, *concerned parents*).

I think you can see that what is being said (though not terribly clearly) is that *concerned* has a different sense depending on whether it is used attributively or postpositively.

Now look up *concerned* in some other dictionaries to understand the difference in sense CGEL is getting at:

*The **concerned** [caring] **students** freed the zoo tigers.*

*The **students concerned** [implicated] were expelled after the freeing the zoo tigers.*

*The **zoo tigers concerned** [involved] were seen wandering the neighborhood.*

***Concerned*** [worried] **neighbors** are staying inside.

Comment: _Merriam Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary_ :          
CONCERNED 2a. having an interest or involvement in something:                      _a discussion that will be of interest to everyone concerned_; _The lawyers called a meeting of all the **concerned parties**_

Comment: @GJC: From CGEL: "Special rules apply with compound determinatives like somebody, anything, etc.: see §9.6."